# New Tag for Vuetify 2.0

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Recently, the Vuetifyjs team released version 2.0.0 of their excellent UI framework. As part of that framework there are a number of breaking changes from version 1.5, for which migration guides have been posted by the devs.

Would it be possible for a new tag to be created for version 2 of the framework, or to retag the existing questions to show that they are for the older version?

Currently, there is only the "vuetify.js" tag, which if searched through by a new user could provide incorrect information if they are using the latest version.

Comment: Are there any questions that _need_ that tag right now? What should the tag excerpt say?